# Reload the same file from the beginning without restarting logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I managed to force Logstash reloading the whole file by pointing the `sincedb_path` to `NUL` (Windows environment) and setting the `start_position` at the beginning. Here is my `file input` configuration:

```
input {
     file {
        path => "myfile.csv"
        start_position => beginning
        ignore_older => 0
        type => "my_document_type"
        sincedb_path => "NUL"
        stat_interval => 1
    }
}
```

The file is actually reloaded every time I restart Logstash and every time it is modified, but I want it to be reloaded each second as mentioned in `stat_interval`.
I also need it to be reloaded even if there is no modification and without restarting logstash because I am adding a date based field in the filters and I need the same data every day with an updated `date_field` :

```
filter {
    csv {
        columns => ["MyFirstColumn", "MySecondColumn"]
        separator => ";"
        add_field => {
        "date_field" => "%{+ddMMyyy}"
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an example of the expected behavior :

File content :

```
Column A;Column B
Value X;Value Y
```

Data sent to Elastic search index :

```
Column A : Value X, Column B : Value Y, date_field : 05122016
```

The day after, even without modifying the file I want the following data to be added to the same index in Elasticsearch :

```
Column A : Value X, Column B : Value Y, date_field : 06122016
```

Comment: what is the content of the file? does it have many or just one line?

Comment: The file contains many lines (semicolon separated values in each line)

Comment: If it comes to file if you are adding new lines it should work and trigger Logstash to read new line. In your case you are updating **existing** lines? If so Logstash has to be restarted according to my knowledge. If adding new lines - what seems to be more natural - no need to restart Logstash or set `sincedb_path`

Comment: When I modify the file it is reloaded automatically. I need the file to be reloaded even without modifying it (the filter will add a different date_field when reloaded in a new day)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally used the `exec` input instead of `file` and launched a `cat` command to read the file every 2 seconds. The cat command retrieve the whole file content so I used a first `split` filter to retrieve each line separately and then a `csv` filter to separate the columns. Here is my config file content :

```
input {
    exec {
        command => "cat myfile.csv"
        interval => 2
        add_field => {
              "tag" => "mytag"
        }
    }
}
filter {    
    if [tag] == "mytag" {
        split {
            terminator => "\n"
        }
        csv {
            columns => ["myFirstColumn", "mySecondColumn", "mythirdColumn"]
            separator => ";"        
        }
}
output {
    if [tag] == "mytag" {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
            index => "myIndex"
        }
    }
}
```

The original answer is available in the [elastic discuss platform](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/reload-the-same-file-from-the-beginning-without-restarting-logstash/68156/3)